# Directorial problems using Java FileReader

Tags: java, filereader

I was following a youtube tutorial explaining the FileReader method and how you had to have a .txt file to read from.
So i created a textfile called JavaText with the directory:

"C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\JavaText.txt"

However eclipse is having problems with the backslashes since they are reserved for e.g "tab" = \t and "new line" = \n

doublechecking the tutorial I was looking, at the FileReader directory the youtuber was using only had slashes "/" and gave no erreros.
I changed my backslashes into regular slashes but now it gave me an error that it couldn't find the file. I suspect I somehow need to specify that the backslashes are indeed part of a String and not to be used for some sort of command but I don't really know how or even if that's 100% the issue.

To clarify I am using Windows 7 and latest version of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a backslash in a string literal you must also escape it as `\\`:

```
String file = "C:\\Users\\Computer\\Desktop\\JavaText.txt";
```

Usually Java also accepts forward slashes as file separator, so you should check if the file does not exist when the program could not find it.

Comment: Windows in general accepts `/` as a directory separator in all API functions. (It could cause problems on the command line / in the console, though.)